# Getting the contents of the pointers in an array of pointers

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, pointers, ctypes

Through ctypes I was able to get the memory address of a buffer containing a sequence of pointers:

```
buff = (ctypes.c_void_p * buff_len).from_address(addr)
arr = np.ndarray((buff_len, ), 'u8', buff, order='C')
```

But what good is getting a series of pointers if I can not get the pointer content with numpy??

What can I do with...?

```
array([1660015432 1660015768 1660015480 1660015720 1660015528 1660015672
       1660015576 1660015624], dtype=uint64)
```

Comment: Why do you expect `numpy` to do this?  This looks like a Python task.  `numpy` arrays normally store their own values in the buffer.  It's only the list like `object` dtype arrays that store pointers.

Comment: @hpaulj, If the buffer is huge, functions with pure python would be very slow

Comment: Object dtype arrays are also slow.  The fast numpy code uses `c` code that works directly on the data buffer.  The kind of indirection that you appear to want has to use Python C-API functions.

Comment: I can't use cpython due to multiplatform incompatibility. But I can use ctypes.pythonapi if necessary.

Comment: Where does the `addr` address come from? What is this array of `void` pointers at `addr`? How is anything supposed to dereference *void* pointers? Given the spacing of the pointers, they may be pointing at elements of an array of 48-byte data structures or maybe rows of a smaller structure. But we can't simply guess.

Comment: @eryksun, I avoided filling up with details so I would not bore people. The address was obtained with a wrap of a user-defined ctypes.Structure to read a hidden attribute from a pyobject. Each pointer points to a struct compiled from C, but if I add an offset to the array, it will point to another pointer (void* with 8 bytes). This other pointer points to another struct, but adding another offset, it will point to an int. In short it's like I'm vectoring a function equal to `lambda ptr: MyCtypesStuct.from_adress(ptr).o1.contents.o2.i`

Comment: `cpython` is the main Python distribution.  If you are using `ctypes` and `numpy` you are most likely also using `cpython`.  You aren't using `pypy` or `jython`, are you?

Comment: @hpaulj, when I said I can not use cpython I was referring to doing a compiled module. But yes,  I can use cpython's api (as long as I do not have to compile)